# SQL statement to show customers that in 2018 bought a product series for the first time that they never bought in the previous years before

Tags: mysql, sql

My database runs on a MySQL Server. SQL Knowledge: Beginner.

Data description:
My database has just 1 table containing sales data. Relevant columns for the query are:

- Year (smallint)
- Customer (text)
- Product_Series (text)
- Total_Sales_EUR (double precision)

Now I would like a SQL-statement to show me a table of customers that bought a Product Series for the first time that they never bought before in the previous years.

So let us say there is a customer who bought Product Series 1,2,3 in previous years and in 2018 bought Product Series 4 for the first time. A customer that bought Product Series 4 in the years before and in 2018 again shall not be displayed in the results table. The result table shall show:

- Year (current year)
- Customer
- Product_Series (that was bought for the first time)
- Total Sales

This is my humble code so far. Totally hitting a rock with the condition.

```
Select "Year", "Customer", "Product_Series", "Total_Sales_EUR"
From databasetable
Where
```

Note: The table does not have a unique key.  Hope it does not complicate things.If I missed any important information, please give me a hint.

Thankful for any kind of help or tip.

Comment: `Now I would like a SQL-statement` ... Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, or a fast food restaurant, where you ask for something and then others go and do it for you.  If you want to learn SQL, you should attempt a query yourself, and only ask for help if you really get stuck.

Comment: Even if you need help with code you don't understand. Post code you have tried. This Question is lacking some important info. Your are asking for an sql statement and you never provide the schema name.

Comment: Hi @Alex, I'm happy you're enjoying yourself on SO. As an academic and a professional in industry, I too, can attest to how much this community has benefited me. However like you, myself, and other members, we do this for the betterment of the community, and therefore we can't simply just write code for you. You need to at least attempt a try at writing this code yourself, and we can take it from there :)

Comment: Thanks for your input @TimBiegeleisen I'm not expecting someone to write the code for me but getting some tips how to structure the code or which functions will help would be nice. Thankful for every helpful contribution.

Comment: Thanks @RyanB and Jerry M., I edited the question.

Comment: Surely you can do better than that.  If that's all you can do with SQL, you should either choose an easier question, or pick up an introductory SQL book and read thoroughly.

Comment: Here is a pretty good course. You can probably spend about 2 hours doing this. And you'll be answering your own question. https://teamtreehouse.com/library/sql-basics

Comment: @Alex here are some hints: look for `group by` and `having` and read up on some conditional functions like `if()`, `case when` etc. Go through tutorials of each one of them and most likely something should start clicking in your mind.

Comment: Thanks for the help, guys. I'll do my homework and when I come up with a solution, I'll complete my question here.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine sql statements using `is [not] in ( ... )` statement. Something like that:

`select users who bought product 1,2,3,4 where user_id not in (select all users_id who did not buy product 4 in 2018)`

Edit: you will need an id since in `is in` statement you can only compare values

OR YOU CAN ALSO LEARN TO CODE BY YOURSELF INSTEAD OF TRYING TO GET OTHERS TO WORK FOR YOU FOR FREE!